# Scala regex not functionning

Tags: regex, scala

I have the following function:

```
val Reg52 = """(?<!\S)(?!(?:[\d.]*\d){6})[0-9]{1,5}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?(?!\S)""".r
def verif_rg52 = udf((s: String) =>
    s match {
      case null            => 0
      case Reg52(item, _*) => 0
      case _               => 1
    })
```

It should verify if a dataframe column contains numbers with format (5,2) -> maximum of 5 digits with at most 2 after the dot. I tested the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/q3l0cX/2) and it works.

But when I try it in Scala:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  "22.0",
  "1000.22"
  ).toDF("id")

df1.withColumn("r", when(verif_rg52(col("id")) === 0 , "0").otherwise("1")).show(false)
```

I get

```
+-------+---+
|id     |r  |
+-------+---+
|22.0   |1  |
|1000.22|1  |
+-------+---+
```

But I should get 0 when id=22.0 because it respects regex. Any help? Thank you

Comment: According to your rules, you could just use `^\d{1,5}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`

Comment: It must be `case Reg52(_*)`, not `Reg52(item, _*)`. Also, the regex you are using is for unanchored matches, if you need to use it as that, append `.unanchored` after `.r`. To match full string, you may replace `(?<!\S)` with `^`  and `(?!\S)` with `$`, or just remove the lookarounds as by default the pattern will have to match the whole string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your regex. All the leading parens, `(`, are followed by a question mark, `?`. You have no capture groups so `case Reg52(item, _*)` doesn't match your pattern.

Use `case Reg52()` or add more parens to specify the capture groups you want.